# Cant Figure out whats wrong with My google sheets api setup?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am on google cloud and im new on it to say the least Im trying to connect my google sheets to a updater tool to input values form Kovaaks aim trainer but i never can get it to work i followed the instructions from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awBoG9Jy8CY. And the only error i get from my end is saying This: "the following email addresses are either not associated with a Google Account or the account is not eligible..." I dont know what todo can someone help?